# Ruby on Rails - Unable to Display Associated Item From Database (#<Comment:0x44f9ec8>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I followed the "Getting Started" tutorial at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, and wanted to change what is output on the articles index page.

rather than showing the text of the article in the main table, I want to see the most recent comment made on that article.

Here is the code for the index:

```
<tr>        

  <td><%= article.title %></td>
  <td><%= article.comments.select(:body).last %></td>

  <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>

  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

Where 'article.comments.select(:body).last' is meant to show the body of the latest comment made on the article in question (this table iterates for every article).

Instead of seeing the text from the comment however, I see this:

## {Comment:0x44f9ec8} (with sharp brackets instead of curly - wont let me post the sharp ones.... <>)

I also tried editing comment.create in the comments_controller with:

**@article.text = @comment.body**

After setting the index table field to 'article.text' (which works fine), but with no effect.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong??
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`article.comments.select(:body).last` does not do what you expect

the `select` part uses this [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) which alters the SQL command you use. It forces selecting only the `body` field from comments and returns a comment object.

so you need to change your code to `article.comments.select(:body).last.body`

If you need to have all the `body` fields and just use one, I suggest that you use [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) if you are on rails > 3.2

`article.comments.pluck(:body).last`

Comment: Just to add to this excellent answer, note that you may want to handle the case where nobody has commented on an article. If that's the case, you may want to show the text... `article.comments.pluck(:body).last || article.text` or perhaps `article.comments.pluck(:body).last || 'no comments on this article'`